# No built-in property editor for the WPF Pen type in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, xaml, pen, custom-properties, propertyeditor

While writing a custom WPF control, I have been surprised that WPF does not provide a built-in visual editor for properties of the System.Windows.Media.Pen type. I expected to see something similar to the editor for Brush-based properties:

[image]

After examining the types of properties used to draw 'something' in some main stock WPF controls (Border, TextBlock, ListView, DataGrid, ...) I saw that they all do not have any Pen properties - only properties based on the Brush type.

Is it a general design concept of WPF and we should also avoid implementing Pen properties in our custom controls?

If implementing a Pen property is still 'eligible', can anybody show an example of doing this? Or do I need to write a property editor from scratch using the techniques described in the [Creating Custom Editors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907382(v=vs.110).aspx) section in the MSDN?

Comment: I believe that when you mentioned WPF it should be replaced with <your IDE name> (Visual Studio, Blend, etc). Because it is not responsibility of WPF.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 able to show Pen properties but there is no dedicated Pen Editor. And I thing that is because Pen is to low abstraction for that.
[![Example.png](https://s23.postimg.org/ibgoa5caj/Example.png)](https://postimg.org/image/h96hrlth3/)

Comment: @lerthe61, I used your suggestion to enhance the question. And yes, we can select a Pen object in XAML to see the VS editor for it - thank you for mentioning this hint. However, this is a 2-step process: first we need to create a Pen object in XAML, and only after that we can edit it visually in the VS property grid. It would be nice to do it at one go as we can do it for Brushes.

Comment: Expression Blend behave just the same. I think that guys from Microsoft just decide not to spend time on that.
And if you navigate on GeometryDrawing you will be able to see Pen editor on the Properties panel. With abilities to change most of  available properties.

Comment: @lerthe61, perhaps, so. But the first question still remains: why the stock WPF controls do not implement Pen properties? Only because of the absent built-in Pen editor in the VS property grid ;) ?